# Sum Columns in a Data Frame

Tags: r, sum

I have a data frame of 8 columns, in which each column is summed to get a total. I must then combine the sums of the first 2 columns, then the next 2, again the next 2, and so on so that I am left with 4 columns (sum of first 2, sum of next 2, etc...).
Here is an example of the data:

```
A B A1 B1 A2 B2 A3 B3 
1 2 1  2  1  1  3  1
2 3 1  1  3  3  2  1
5 6 6  4  3  2  1  1
```

This is the code that I used, in which I was able to successfully do this:

```
ColumnSums<-lapply(ColumnSums, function(x) sum(x))

AB<-ColumnSums$A+ColumnSums$B
A1B1<-ColumnSums$A1+ColumnSums$B1
A2B2<-ColumnSums$A2+ColumnSums$B2
A3B3<-ColumnSums$A3+ColumnSums$B3

CombinedTotals<-c(AB,A1B1,A2B2,A3B3)
names(CombinedTotals)<-c("AB","A1B1","A2B2","A3B3")
```

I am just wondering if there is a way to trim this code down. Specifically, the second part of my code. I had to manually combine each total for 2 columns. I am wondering if there is a way to automate that process.

Comment: yes there is a way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this simply, if `df` is your original `data.frame`:

```
setNames(colSums(df)[c(F, T)]+colSums(df)[c(T,F)], c("AB","A1B1","A2B2","A3B3"))
#AB A1B1 A2B2 A3B3 
#19   15   13    9
```

Or:

```
tapply(colSums(df), (seq(ncol(df))-1) %/% 2, sum)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Even shorter than what I was thinking would be the solution. Thank you!

Comment: +1 Just a little suggestion.  It would be quicker if you assigned the `colSums()` result in the first line so that you aren't calculating it twice.  Just in case the data is huge

Comment: true my solution doubles the time, just wanted a one liner ^ ^